# How to place the footer to the bottom of the page a size when using a card in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using a card and after the card I put my footer. But the footer is of very large size as compared to the one mentioned in its css.

Image -

[image]

Code -

app.component.html -

```
<div class="card" id="card-css">
    <div class="card-body">
  //code

    </div>
  </div>

  <hr class="line" color="#f5821f;" />

  <div class="footer text-right" style = "height:50px !important" >
    <label style="color: black">Â© 2018 ICICI. API Developer</label>
  </div>
```

app.component.css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: white; 
   color: black;
   text-align: center; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
   }
```

Comment: *But the footer is of very large size* can you just elaborate this please?

Comment: Like , I have put the footer height as 50px, but the height is coming very large than 50px

Comment: if you inspect the DOM, it shows as *50px* itself.

Comment: yes ...it is showing

Comment: so then, what is the issue?

Comment: please demonstrate using codepen /code-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting the question correctly then I think you want your footer at bottom of the page. For this you just need to change your bellow css.

```
position: relative
```

to

```
position: fixed;
margin:10px;
```

and for text size you can add the below css if you want.

```
font-size: 25px;
```

Comment: sorry ! .. no difference in the size. Only  the name is come below

Comment: Your question was clearly asking about the bottom. I have edited the answer please try that.

Comment: What I have found out is, when in a card , no data is present then the footer is way more than the original size. But when data appears and page fills up then the footer becomes normal

Comment: Cool. But your question seems more related to have the footer at bottom of the page. Well Cheers.